# Converting VB conditions to SQL conditions

Tags: sql, vb.net

There are some VB conditions that I need to execute in SQL query. Is this possible? Here's the code:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

    Dim timeIn = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeIn").ToString
    Dim timeOut = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeOut").ToString


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeIn) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeOut) Then

        Dim result = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(timeIn), Convert.ToDateTime(timeOut)) 
If result > 0 Then 'last timeIn later than last timeOut
            attendanceStatus = "On"
        Else
            attendanceStatus = "Off"
        End If

    ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeIn) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeOut) Then

        attendanceStatus = "On"

        End If

        lblAttendStatus.Text = attendanceStatus

    End If

End If
```

Comment: If you call a stored procedure, then you can add in parameters which could contain values based on your VB logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by including in your SQL statement after SELECT:

```
CASE WHEN TimeIn < TimeOut THEN 'Off' ELSE 'On' END AS attendanceStatus,
```